# Could not run spring boot multi module war file

Tags: angular, maven, spring-boot, tomcat8

I have created spring boot and angular 8 multi module maven project. I can run the application by navigating to backend module and `mvn spring-boot:run` , application running successfully. However, If I create a war and giving same run command, I am getting below error:

```
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml (20 kB at 54 kB/s)
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml (14 kB at 36 kB/s)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.009 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-10-07T11:50:14-04:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'spring-boot' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/Users/<domain>/.m2/repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
```

War file is creating in backend/target. Let me know if you need any other information.
parent.pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.company</groupId>
  <artifactId>Dashboard</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>Dashboard</name>
   <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
  <modules>
  <module>Frontend</module>
  <module>Backend</module>

  </modules>
</project>
```

Front-end.pom.xml

```
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>Dashboard</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>Frontend</artifactId>

  <name>Frontend</name>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <nodeVersion>v10.16.3</nodeVersion>
                    <npmVersion>6.9.0</npmVersion>
                    <workingDirectory>src/main/web/</workingDirectory>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install node and npm</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>npm install</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>npm run build</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>run build</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>prod</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>run-script build</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

backend.pom.xml

```
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.componay</groupId>
    <artifactId>Dashboard</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>Backend</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>Backend</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
   <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--This dependency includes JPA, JPA Implementation. default JPA implementaiton 
            is hibernate. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId><!-- managed version is 8.0.17 
                with spring boot 2.1.8 RELEASE -->
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.company</groupId>
            <artifactId>Frontend</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <warName>Dashboard</warName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>

                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/src/main/resources/static</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${project.parent.basedir}/Frontend/src/main/web/dist/Dashboard/</directory>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Deployed war file into tomact webapps folder, started tomcat, application started without errors. But could not access index.html page. Getting 404-Not found. Error:  The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Comment: My bad, context path was different. spring context path from application.properties file is not being read, war file name is takes a context-path. Issue fixed, anyway. Not sure, why context path configured in application.properties file is not being read. I am closing this thread for now.

Answer (score 0):

My bad, context path was different. spring context path from application.properties file is not being read, war file name is takes a context-path.